# How to create chat activity with text and images messages

Tags: android, listview, textview, imageview, chat

Currently i'am developing a some messaging application.
Server side can take me a text with some bb codes: `Check this out! :) [IMG]http://somedomain.com/image.jpg[/IMG] [IMG]http://domain.com/image3.jpg[/IMG]`

For parsing smiles i use these code:

```
public class BbCodedText {
private static final Factory spannableFactory = Spannable.Factory
        .getInstance();

private static final Map<Pattern, Integer> emoticons = new HashMap<Pattern, Integer>();

static {
    addPattern(emoticons, ":)", R.drawable.smile_face);
    addPattern(emoticons, ":))", R.drawable.smile_very_face);
    addPattern(emoticons, ":)))", R.drawable.joy_face);
}

private static void addPattern(Map<Pattern, Integer> map, String smile,
                               int resource) {
    map.put(Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(smile)), resource);
}

public static boolean addSmiles(Context context, Spannable spannable) {
    boolean hasChanges = false;
    for (Map.Entry<Pattern, Integer> entry : emoticons.entrySet()) {
        Matcher matcher = entry.getKey().matcher(spannable);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            boolean set = true;
            for (ImageSpan span : spannable.getSpans(matcher.start(), matcher.end(), ImageSpan.class))
                if (spannable.getSpanStart(span) >= matcher.start()
                        && spannable.getSpanEnd(span) <= matcher.end())
                    spannable.removeSpan(span);
                else {
                    set = false;
                    break;
                }
            if (set) {
                hasChanges = true;

                Drawable emoji = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, entry.getValue());
                emoji.setBounds(0,0, 30, 30);


                spannable.setSpan(
                        new ImageSpan(emoji, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE),
                        matcher.start(), matcher.end(),
                        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
                );
            }
        }
    }

    return hasChanges;
}

public static Spannable getSmiledText(Context context, CharSequence text) {
    Spannable spannable = spannableFactory.newSpannable(text);
    addSmiles(context, spannable);
    return spannable;
}
}
```

And smiles works fine:

[image]

But how i can change my Adapter, Activity, or somethins else to use images in chat message like this:

[image]

Comment: create two child layout one for text and one for image and then depending on type of layout inflate respective layout

Comment: Ok. It is a good idea for one image.
But if a have two or more images at one message: 
Check this out! :) [IMG]http://somedomain.com/imageONe.jpg[/IMG] [IMG]http://domain.com/imageTwo.jpg[/IMG] [IMG]http://domain.com/imageThree.jpg[/IMG] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem with using custom FlowLayout and `addView` function.

I've added `FlowLayout` to my layout file for `ListView` item:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/groupDivider"
        android:id="@+id/messageContainer"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/messageBody"
            />

        <com.example.components.FlowLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/messageMediaContainer">
        </com.example.components.FlowLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            style="@style/SmallText"
            android:id="@+id/messageDate"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Whan i parse message body and crop some tags with pictures. And write some code to my `Adapter`:

```
holder.mediaView = (FlowLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.messageMediaContainer);
        ...
        ...
holder.mediaView.removeAllViews();

// imagesSrc contains image URLs
for(int i=0; i<imagesSrc.size(); i++) {
   final String url = imagesSrc.get(i);
   ImageView img = new ImageView(this.context);

   FlowLayout.LayoutParams params = new FlowLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);           
   img.setLayoutParams(params);
   img.setImageDrawable(null);
   img.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));

   holder.mediaView.addView(img);        

   // load image into imageView here
}
```

The result is:
[image]